# How to use x:Object and when?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When passing arguments by the markup extension `x:Arguments` to non default constructors as specified by the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments/), I can see the use of concrete data types such as `x:Int32` or `x:String`, but what's the use case of `x:Object`? And what's more, to use it, what should be put between the tag? `<x:Object> ??? </x:Object>`

In the case of integer or string, it is natural to think them as an variable assignment and the variables then get passed to the constructors. But in the case of `Object`, such an variable normally is constructed by another user defined class, so how to specify what class you want to create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can pass `x:Object` as constructor argument. `x:Object` corresponds to `System.Object` which does have default constructor. So if you have

```
 public class MyClass {
     public MyClass(object arg) {

     }
 }
```

You can construct it like this:

```
<my:MyClass>
  <x:Arguments>
    <x:Object />
  </x:Arguments>
</my:MyClass>
```

But this is not quite useful, because it will correspond to

```
new MyClass(new object());
```

Since `Object` does not have any other constructors - you cannot construct it in any other meaningful way. So when constructor expects argument of type object - you don't want to use `x:Object` but instead actual type:

```
<my:MyClass>
  <x:Arguments>
    <x:String>string</x:String>
  </x:Arguments>
</my:MyClass>
```

which corresponds to

```
new MyClass("string");
```

Answer (score 4):

#### x:Object

The **x:Object** primitive corresponds to Object. This primitive is not typically used in application markup but might be useful for some scenarios such as checking assignability in a XAML type system. You can use as Argument.

Take a look at the [Xamarin documentation on Resource Dictionaries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments/) for a full explanation on how to use the x:Key attribute of your resources.

> Each resource has a key that is specified using the x:Key attribute,
>   which gives it a descriptive key in the ResourceDictionary.

You can use it like below:

```
<local:MockFactory >
     <x:Arguments>
         <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:Object}">
             <x:String>Foo</x:String>
             <x:String>Bar</x:String>
         </x:Array>
     </x:Arguments>
</local:MockFactory>
```

you can find a related example [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.UnitTests/FactoryMethods.xaml)

Comment: I think your example is showing x:String, not x:Object. I'm looking for an usage of <x:Object>...</x:Object>

Answer (score 2):

Data Templates that define their data type as x:Object are excellent fallback data templates when dealing with data of an unsupported type.

Lets say you have a screen that shows up and informs the user that if the data they import is unsupported, they will see the result as follows: and then you show the data template for x:Object. An easy way to do this would be like this:

```
<ContentControl>
  <ContentControl.Content>
    <x:Object/>
  </ContentControl.Content>
</ContentControl>
```

so that the most specific data template available is the x:Object one, and that is what is shown.

the Object class contains no meaningful data, so there is not really any reason to write

```
<x:Object></x:Object>
```

because there is no content for the type.