# How to pass a view as constructor argument in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom View that displays some inner content in a formatted way, and would like to give it that content from XAML. [The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments) explain how to use basic types, but not how to pass it a View:

> Arguments can be passed to a non-default constructor using the
>   x:Arguments attribute. Each constructor argument must be delimited
>   within an XML element that represents the type of the argument.
>   Xamarin.Forms supports the following elements for basic types:
>
> x:Object
>   x:Boolean
>   x:Byte
>   x:Int16
>   x:Int32
>   x:Int64
>   x:Single
>   x:Double
>   x:Decimal
>   x:Char
>   x:String
>   x:TimeSpan
>   x:Array
>   x:DateTime

[This QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845405/how-to-use-xobject-and-when) explains that using `x:Object` is not the way to go.

So how can I pass, from XAML, a View as Constructor argument to my Custom View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the list from the docs is not extensive.
If you have your custom View with a constructor like

```cs
public CustomView(View Icon) : this()
{
    SetInnerContent(Icon);
}
```

It is possible to pass a view from xaml like this:

```xml
<CustomView>
    <x:Arguments>
        <Image Source="somepath"/>
    </x:Arguments>
</CustomView>
```

There is no need to rely on any of the listed `x:something` options.

Comment: When i try to type : this() it says "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter", my parameter is a double

Comment: @Steven it's been four years, and maybe something regarding this has changed in the docs. But if your parameter is a double, then going by what I quoted in my question, you should be able to use `<x:Double` where I used `<Image` in my answer. Probably you don't even need the `: this()` call -- do you even have another constructor for your class? iirc the point of my `: this()` is to invoke the default constructor of my `CustomView`. Or if you do have to call another constructor, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/985325/2550406)